# ¿Cómo incluir una nueva columna con la traducción de otra en un DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, traducción

Estoy intentando agregar una nueva columna a un DataFrame existente. La nueva columna que intento agregar es la traducción de otra columna llamada 'Titular' la cual contiene los encabezados de un periódico, pero por algún motivo esta nueva columna no se agrega y como resultado de este scrypt obtengo exactamente el mismo DataFrame original que se llama `df_todos1`. Agrego una función `try` y `except` ya que si no los agrego, como resultado obtengo un error del tipo `Attribute Error`, más concretamente:

```
NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Este es el script original:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

for i in df_todos1['Titular']:
  try:
    df_todos1['Titular_eng'] = df_todos1['Titular'].apply(translator.translate, src='es', 
dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
  except AttributeError:
    continue

print(df_todos1)
```

Answer (score 0):

La versión que usas de `googletrans` tiene un [bug](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234) que causa ese error.

Lo puedes solucionar desinstalando `googletrans` e instalando la versión `4.0.0-rc1`, de la siguiente manera:

```
pip uninstall googletrans
pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1
```

Para lo que quieres hacer no necesitas iterar con un `for`. A continuación te muestro dos maneras de hacer lo que quieres, una por medio de declarar una función y la otra con una función lambda.

```
from googletrans import Translator  # version 4.0.0-rc1
import pandas as pd

data = {'Escritor': ['Ruben', 'Alex'],
        'Titular': ['El periodico de hoy', 'El periodico de ayer']}
df_todos1 = pd.DataFrame (data)

translator = Translator()


# Metodo 1: Definiendo una funcion
def traducir(df_todos1):
    traduccion = translator.translate(df_todos1['Titular'], src='es', dest='en')
    return traduccion.text

df_todos1['Titular_eng'] = df_todos1.apply(traducir, axis=1)


# Metodo 2: Usando una funcion lambda
df_todos1['Titular_eng'] = df_todos1.apply(lambda df_todos1 : translator.translate(df_todos1['Titular'], src='es', dest='en').text, axis=1)


print(df_todos1)
```

Devuelve:

```
  Escritor               Titular            Titular_eng
0    Ruben   El periodico de hoy      Today's newspaper
1     Alex  El periodico de ayer  Yesterday's newspaper
```